# How select count distinct (unique truckers) without group by function and maybe without using Having (not sure about last)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a task, but couldn't solve it:

There are truckers and they have to travel between cities.
We have data of these travels in our database in 2 tables:

1. trucker_traffic

   ```
    tt_id (key)                
    date                
    starting_point_coordinate                
    destination_coordinate                
    traveller_id                
    event_type ('travel', 'accident')                
    parent_event_id (For 'accident' event type it's tt_id of the original travel. There might be few accidents within one travel.)
   ```
2. trucker_places

   ```
    coordinate (key)                
    country                
    city
   ```

I need SQL query to pull the number of all unique truckers who travelled more than once from or to London city in June 2020.
In the same query pull the number of these travels who got into an accident.

Example of my tries

```
SELECT
    count(distinct(tt.traveller_id)),
        
FROM trucker_traffic tt

JOIN trucker_places tp
    ON tt.starting_point_coordinate = tp.coordinate
     OR tt.destination_coordinate   = tp.coordinate
WHERE 
    tp.city = 'London'
    AND month(tt.date) = 6
    AND year(tt.date) = 2020
    
GROUP BY tt.traveller_id

HAVING count(tt.tt_id) > 1
```

But it's select count distinct truckers with grouping and works only if I had one tracker in db

For second part of task (where I have select number of travels with accident - I think that good to use function like this

```
SUM(if(count(tt_id = parent_event_id),1,0))
```

But I'm not sure

Comment: Why do you say in the title that `GROUP BY` must not be used? This makes the task much more difficult.

Comment: On a side note: You may want to limit the country to England, as there exist other cities with the same name in the world (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_(disambiguation)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather complicated, so make sure you do this step by step. `WITH` clauses help with this.

### Steps

1. Find travels from and to London in June 2020. You can use `IN` or `EXISTS` in order to see whether a travel had accidents.
2. Group the London travels by traveller, count travels and accident travels and only keep those travellers with more than one travel.
3. Take this result set to count the travellers and sum up their travels.

### Query

```
with london_travels as
(
  select 
    traveller_id,
    case when tt_id in
      (select parent_event_id from trucker_traffic where event_type = 'accident')
    then 1 else 0 end as accident
  from trucker_traffic tt
  where event_type = 'travel'
  and month(tt.date) = 6
  and year(tt.date) = 2020
  and exists
  (
    select 
    from trucker_places tp
    where tp.coordinate in (tt.starting_point_coordinate, tt.destination_coordinate)
    and tp.city = 'London'
  )
)
, london_travellers as
(
  select 
    traveller_id,
    count(*) as travels,
    sum(accident) as accident_travels
  from london_travels
  group by traveller_id
  having count(*) > 1;
)
select
  count(*) as total_travellers,
  sum(travels) as total_travels,
  sum(accident_travels) as total_accident_travels
from london_travellers;
```

If your MySQL version doesn't support `WITH` clauses, you can of course just nest the queries. I.e.

```
with a as (...), b as (... from a) select * from b;
```

becomes

```
select * from (... from (...) a) b;
```

You say in the request title that you don't want `GROUP BY` in the query. This is possible, but makes the query more complicated. If you want to do this I leave this as a task for you. Hint: You can select travellers and count in subqueries per traveller.